# fastlane cannot export ipa

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

My project is using Automatically managing signing

When I want to use fastlane to export ipa, I got following error

I could find archive file in Xcode's Organizer window

but could not export to ipa file

Is there something I didn't notice?

lane:

```
lane :CIUAT do
    gym(scheme: "MyApp",
        clean: true,
        export_method: "development",
        output_name: "MyApp.ipa",
        xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates",
        include_symbols: true,
        include_bitcode: false
    )
end
```

error:

```
[14:09:32]: ▸ Command line invocation:
[14:09:32]: ▸     
[14:09:32]: 
[14:09:32]: ⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error
[14:09:32]:   For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:
[14:09:32]:   /Users/jeff/Library/Logs/gym/MyApp-MyApp.log
[14:09:32]: 
[14:09:32]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[14:09:32]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[14:09:32]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[14:09:32]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[14:09:32]: sure your project is set up correctly.
[14:09:32]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[14:09:32]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[14:09:32]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[14:09:32]: 
+------------------+-----------+
|         Lane Context         |
+------------------+-----------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios       |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | ios       |
| LANE_NAME        | ios CIUAT |
| VERSION_NUMBER   | 1.7.6     |
+------------------+-----------+
[14:09:32]: Error building the application - see the log above

+------+--------------------+-------------+
|            fastlane summary             |
+------+--------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action             | Time (in s) |
+------+--------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform   | 0           |
| 2    | cocoapods          | 4           |
| 3    | get_version_number | 0           |
|    | build_app          | 536         |
+------+--------------------+-------------+

[14:09:32]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Error building the application - see the log above
```

Comment: From your code I see that you define schemeName variable but then uses another variable MyApp for scheme... Also uses some outputPath variable. Please check that both MyApp and outputPath variables are defined somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You export method is set to development it should be set for AppStore if you want to upload on AppStore and if you want distribute app for testing only then it should be set to AdHoc
change export method to:
export_method: "app-store"
and provide provisional profiles
Check more details here https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/build_ios_app/